# How multi-select work in rofi dmenu

Tags: bash, zsh, rofi

I am using `rofi 1.5.4`

Suppose I run the command

```
echo -e "Option #1\nOption #2\nOption #3" | rofi -dmenu -multi-select | xargs -I{} echo {}
```

What keys shall I use to select multiple menu item?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP here, To populate the menu you can use the code I mentioned in the question.

Then go to the menu items and use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>